# List comprehensions in jinja template using build in filters

Tags: python, list, jinja2, list-comprehension

New to jinja and python so wanted to see if I can get some help on how to use build in filters to convert a list comprehension that I created after reading about it. But unfortunately it looks like it won't work with jinja and I have to find a equivalent of list comprehension using filters?

This is the list comprehension that I created after reading about it.

```
{% answerdata = [d for d in data if d['question_instance_id'] == question.question_id] %}
```

Now I want to write the equivalent for this that jinja would understand?

Comment: Templates are for displaying things, in general you shouldn't create new variables inside a template, even if you can. The `answerdata` variable should have been computed in advance, and passed in the context dictionary.

Comment: Yeah but in this case I want to display the radio button based on the conditions that involve answer data for each question. So not sure how can I do it outside of the template.

Comment: See my answer for an alternative method.

Answer (score 0):

Templates are for presentation. Instead of trying to create a variable, you can iterate over the data directly, i.e.:

```
{% for d in data %}
  {% if d.question_instance_id == question.question_id %}
    <!-- display radio button -->
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: can I use a build in filter that jinja offers? something like this if this is correct..

answerdata = {{ (data|selectattr('question_instance_id', 'eq', question.question_id)|first).response_answer }}

Comment: No, I don't think you can do this using built-in filters.